# How to erase flash memory in a module

Tags: flash, embedded-linux, erase

On my Linux system I can erase flash memory from the command line by using the flash_erase program from the mtd library.
But I need to erase an mtd partition in a module.
In the kernel include files I found linux/mtd/mtd.h, but that defines structures, not functions to call.
Is there someone out there who can point me in the right direction to do this?
Thanks,
Han

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this from a kernel module. Just start a user mode helper process and do it the way it is supposed to work.

Comment: My module is controlling the contents of two mtd partitions and an erase of (part of) the partitionj is needed sometimes. Are you suggesting that the preferred way of doing this is having the module activate a user mode helper function?

Comment: Right! I figured out what a user mode helper function is and implemented a call to